# Update input value dynamically & update another element after dynamic input change

Tags: jquery, forms, events, input, dynamically-generated

Below is the sample HTML and JS that I created for the problem that I am having. I have a form that has three inputs. The value from the first two inputs will dictate the value of the third. I also want the values of all three inputs to display in `<p>` tags outside of the form. I have been able to update the first two `<p>` tags outside the form correctly, and I have been able to update the third input value correctly. However, I cannot get the third `<p>` tag to update when the third input value has dynamically changed.

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmpmJV) for the problem.

HTML

```
<form>
  <input id="one" type="number" class="sumVari" name="a"> 
  <input id="two" type="number" class="sumVari" name="b">
  <input id="three" type="number" name="sum" placeholder="sum of a & b">
</form>
<div id="displayValues">
  <p>The value of a is: <span id="a"></span> </p>
  <p>The value of a is: <span id="b"></span></p>
  <p>The value of the sum is: <span id="sum"></span></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
let one = $('#one');
let two = $('#two');
let three = $('#three');

$('form').on('change', 'input', function() {
  let target = $(this);
  let attrName = target.attr('name');

  $('#'+attrName).text(target.val());
});

function sum(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}

$('.sumVari').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    if(one.val() != '' && two.val() != '') {
      three.val(sum(one.val(), two.val()));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Call the change event manually when putting value on the sum

```js
let one = $('#one');
let two = $('#two');
let three = $('#three');

$('form').on('change', 'input', function() {
  let target = $(this);
  let attrName = target.attr('name');

  $('#' + attrName).text(target.val());
});

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

$('.sumVari').each(function() {
  $(this).change(function() {
    if (one.val() != '' && two.val() != '') {
      three.val(sum(one.val(), two.val())).change();//call the change event manually here on the sum input so that the change function will run on the sum input
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="one" type="number" class="sumVari" name="a">
  <input id="two" type="number" class="sumVari" name="b">
  <input id="three" type="number" name="sum" placeholder="sum of a & b">
</form>
<div id="displayValues">
  <p>The value of a is: <span id="a"></span> </p>
  <p>The value of a is: <span id="b"></span></p>
  <p>The value of the sum is: <span id="sum"></span></p>
</div>
```